# How to resize the programmatically created UILabel,UITextView,UITextfield in programmatically created scroll view as per orientation change

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have created programmatically created scrollview It resizes as per orientation. But the UI elements created on the scroll view are fixed it is not changes. Now I need to change the UILabel,UITextView,UITextfield size as per orientation I tried with below code but its not work for me.

```
CGRect textfieldFrame = CGRectMake(12.0, 20.0, textView.frame.size.width-20,     textView.frame.size.height-424);
//CGRect textfieldFrame = CGRectMake(12.0, 20.0, 270, 35);/* I used For fixed size
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:textfieldFrame];
[textField setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[textField setAutoresizingMask:
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
 textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Now I have to resize the elements as per orientation change. How to solve this problem?

Comment: why not use autolayout

Comment: In my application  required to create the UI-Elements dynamically

Comment: you acheve dynamic layout in autolayout

Comment: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/raymond-robinson/ios-6-tutorial-dynamic-interfaces-auto-layout

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this

Comment: you are working entirely by code

Answer (score 0):

Hey Anupama Try this

```
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIApplication 
    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || 
    orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)

      {
           // your frame for landscape             

       }
    else if(orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
       {
         // your frame for portrait

       }
```

Comment: I need to create UIElements dynamically.The sizes of the UIElement resizable according to view.How to fix the resizable size

Comment: If you get any delegate api/notification api when your UIView is resized,then u can write your own logic to resize your UIElements using setFrame.